# Discord.js Discord Bot: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: discord, discord.js

```
msg.guild.channels.find(c => c.id == "693088078168064051").send(tempVars("absence_review"))
.then(function(message) {
        const approved = message.react("✅")
            .then(() => message.react("❌"))
            .catch(error => {});

        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return ['✅', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
        };

        message.awaitReactions(filter, {
                max: 1
            })
            .then(collected => {
                const reaction = collected.first();
                if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅', reaction.user.bot === false) {
                    message.reply('reacted with yee.');
                } else if (reaction.emoji.name === '❌', reaction.user.bot === false) {
                    message.reply('reacted with nah dude.');
                }
            })
            .catch(collected => {
                message.reply('you didnt react idiot');
            });
```

That is the code I am currently using for the command. What I am making this command to do is to record an absence, send it to another channel with reactions, have someone react to it and if they react with the checkmark, it will send it back to the channel where the command was originally sent, but if they react to the cross, the person who originally made the command gets DM'd by the bot. Those last few things are easy, but my main issue is the reactions. I have made the reactions appear, but the last bit of the code seems to break it. Everything after the 'const filter' bit. If I remove all that, then it will just send the embed message with the reactions, but the reactions won't do anything. However, if I keep that in. It won't even send the message, I get an error stating "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" Now I have googled for this for around an hour, getting friends to help but unfortunately nothing is helping. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot see the whole code, I believe your error is thrown not from the code above. The syntax error 'unexpected end of input' is usually caused by not finishing a bracket or brackets i.e `)};` in somewhere in your code - commonly after the 'client on' function in your main.js file. Go through your whole code and make sure every bracket is properly represented. Maybe put your code into code.vb - it detects and points out syntax errors like the one you have above.

Let me know of progress.

Comment: The reaction emoji name works like that perfectly, :white_check_mark: is also going to likely work, but the Unicode characters are recommended and they worked perfectly fine for me in the past.

As for the rest of the code I forgot to actually point out (sorry) that I am using Discord Bot Maker and this is the script I am making in a 'Run Script' action, so the error is in there.

Comment: `.then(() => message.react("❌"))` I don't fully understand this line, is this the correct syntax? I would strongly recommend to put your code into Visual Studio Code - it will find your error.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent yet another 3 hours in my mini dungeon figuring this out and got something to somewhat work.

```
msg.guild.channels.find(c => c.id == "693088078168064051")
.send(tempVars("absence_review")).then(function(message){
        message.react("✅")
            .then(() => message.react("❌"))
            .catch(error => {});
});
        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return ['✅', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
        };

    message.awaitReactions(filter, {
            max: 1
        })
        .then(collected => {
            const reaction = collected.first();
            if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅', reaction.user.bot === false) {
                message.reply('reacted with yee.');
            } else if (reaction.emoji.name === '❌', reaction.user.bot === false) {
                message.reply('reacted with nah dude.');
            }
        })
        .catch(collected => {
            message.reply('you didnt react idiot');
        });
```

This is a fixed version of it, although the last bit doesn't necessarily work, I will try figure the rest out by myself.